# Can't remove old version of ChromeDriver on MacOS

Tags: macos, homebrew, selenium-chromedriver

I have a very annoying problem with ChromeDriver. I need to use version 2.36, but I currently have 2.35.528157 (when doing `chromedriver -v`).

I have already done:

```
brew upgrade chromedriver
```

Which ran successfully, however according to my terminal, I still have 2.35.528157

I then did a

```
brew cleanup chromedriver
```

which got rid of versions 2.34 and 2.35 according to its logs, however when I do `chromedriver -v` I still get 2.35.528157.

If I do: `brew list chromedriver`, all I get is the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.36/bin/chromedriver
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.36/homebrew.mxcl.chromedriver.plist
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally installed it through npm, so I suppose that was the one taking priority.

I could not update it via npm for some reason, so I just downloaded the latest version of [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Deleted the old version of the file in my npm directory, and put the new one in its place. Not sure if it's the best practice or the actual solution but at least I got it working.

Comment: Is this the directory: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/usr/local/lib/node_modules ?
I tried the same but I am not able to find the chromedriver in npm directory.... Is the file by the same name ?

Answer (score 1):

```
brew uninstall --cask chromedriver
```

Comment: Mind to explain what the advantages of your command compared to the other answers is?

Comment: brew cask commands were deprecated on 2020-12-01 with the release of Homebrew 2.6.
https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall the old version as:

```
brew cask uninstall chromedriver
```

And then install last ( needed ) version by

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

So, right now my version is ok:

```
chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416})
```

And Selenium works properly